# Optimized hive data aggregation using hive

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, hive, distributed-computing, bigdata

I have a hive table (80 million records) with the followig schema (event_id ,country,unit_id,date) and i need to export this data to a text file as with the following requirments:
1-Rows are aggregated(combined) by event_id.
2-Aggregated rows must be sorted according to date.

For example rows with same event_id must be combined as a list of lists, ordered according to date.

What is the best performance wise solution to make this job using spark ?

Note: This is expected to be a batch job.

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, I think the best solution is to write a spark program (scala or python) to read in the underlying files to the hive table, do your transformations, and then write the output as a file.

I've found that it's much quicker to just read the files in spark rather than querying hive through spark and pulling the result into a dataframe.